# Wait for completion of tasks of subscribers of ConnectableObservable

Tags: java, kotlin, observable, reactive-programming, reactive

I created an observable that is going to be used via multiple subscribers that making some resource-intensive tasks with emits. Using like this:

```
val connectableObservable = Observable.create {...}.publish()
connectableObservable.doOnNext {...}.subscribe()
connectableObservable.doOnNext {...}.subscribe()
connectableObservable.connect()
```

Unfortunately, connect() is only synchronously waiting for a source not for subscribers to complete tasks. Is there a way to wait for subscribers of ConnectableObservable to finish tasks and only then continue execution?

Comment: Solved with removing .observeOn() from subscriber. I wonder if there a way to use multi-threading with .connect() in such way.

Answer (score 0):

One of may subscribers contained .observeOn(Schedulers.io()) which sends emits to specified Scheduler. Probably .connect() only wait for current thread. Removing it solves the problem.